# It's lash, tail hit or tailstrike?

Tags: expressions

Violent movement that some animals do with the tail.

One of the attacks of Riptor from Killer Instinct (I could not find a real animal that uses the tail to attack)

I would go for tail hit or tail-hit but I could not find a text where it is used.

"Lash" came from Google Translator.

It's not for use in a sentence. It's the name of an attack move for a video game project. Trying to translate it to English. The creature it's supposed to hit with its tail.

Imagine a button with the name of the attack move:

[ Tail Hit ] [ Fire Blow ] [ Kick ]

Comment: Neither tail hit or tail strike are commonly used phrases.  So to better answer your question, can you provide an example sentence?  I do not know if there is a definitive answer to your question.  It will depend on the person speaking and the exact situation they are describing.

Comment: @KumaAra It's not for use in a sentence. It's the name of an attack move for a video game project. Trying to translate it to English. The creature it's supposed to hit with its tail.

Comment: Okay, that helps a lot.  Then please edit your question to include that information.

Comment: Tail hit, tail lash, tail whip, and others, are all possibilities; but I've voted to close this question as opinion based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a video game, I recommend using 'tail whip' as the name of an attack.

[Tail whip is a common attack in the pokemon franchise.](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Tail_Whip_(move))  So it would sound very natural to most English speaking gamers.

The [definition of whip from dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/whip) is:

> 2. to strike with quick, repeated strokes of something slender and flexible; lash

To address your other suggestions: tail hit, tail strike, tail lash

[Please look here for a graph of how common all four phrases are.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tail%20hit%2C%20tail%20whip%2C%20tail%20strike%2C%20tail%20lash&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctail%20hit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctail%20whip%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctail%20strike%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctail%20lash%3B%2Cc0)

**Tail strike** and **tail lash** are not very common phrases. [And **tail strike** is a specific term in aviation that does not have the meaning you are looking for.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tailstrike)  Therefore I do not recommend these two.

**Tail hit** and **tail whip** are about equal in how often they are used.  The main difference is that **tail whip** is used in Pokemon, and therefore is very familiar to gamers.  In fact, I bet the rise in usage of **tail whip** seen on the graph is because of the release of Pokemon Red in the late 1990's.

The difference in meaning between **tail hit** and **tail whip** is that **tail whip** implies the tail is rapidly whipped at the enemy, in the same way that one uses an actual whip.  But **tail hit** is more general, and could imply a varying range of speeds or strengths.